# How to get the transfer time in a custom Fiddler inspector

Tags: fiddler, extensibility

I am writing a custom Fiddler inspector (inheriting from Inspector2 and implementing IResponseInspector2), and one of the things I want to show in the output of the inspector is the time it took for the response to come back from the server (relative to the time the corresponding request was sent from the client).

I basically want the user to see how long the request took without them having to switch to the Timeline view.

Does anyone know if there is a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - I found a way, but it seems sort of hacky - maybe there is a better way.

```
Session[] sessions = FiddlerApplication.UI.GetSelectedSessions();
if (sessions != null && sessions.Length == 1)
{
    Session s = sessions[0];
    if (s != null && (s.state == SessionStates.Done))
    {
        TimeSpan totalTime = s.Timers.ClientDoneResponse - s.Timers.ClientBeginRequest;
        Debug.WriteLine("Time = " + totalTime.ToString());
    }
}
```

I guess I want a more elegant way to get the `Session` associated with the response that the inspector is currently processing.

Comment: This complex topic is well covered in the upcoming Fiddler book. Short answer is that you should override the virtual AssignSession function on your Inspector2 implementation. In that, you'll use the session provided to set your inspector's headers and body properties, and you can keep a reference to the Session object handy for looking at timers, etc.

Comment: Thanks Eric - Fiddler is awesome!

Answer (score 1):

in FilderScript find variable m_ShowTTLB and  m_ShowTimestamp and set all to true.
Show the result into Custom column

```
    // Show the duration between the start of Request.Send and Response.Completed in Milliseconds
    public static RulesOption("&Show Time-to-Last-Byte", "Per&formance")
    var m_ShowTTLB: boolean = true;

    // Show the time of response completion
    public static RulesOption("Show Response &Timestamp", "Per&formance")
    var m_ShowTimestamp: boolean = true;
```